# com.db4o.internal.query.ObjectSetFacade' was not included

Tags: gwt, db4o

GWT + Springs + DB4o: Any idea how to make this work without adding a new RPC class

[WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.db4o.internal.query.ObjectSetFacade' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = [com.ppp.prm.portal.shared.dto.MComments@2214ab5, com.ppp.prm.portal.shared.dto.MComments@4fda105f, com.ppp.prm.portal.shared.dto.MComments@7568f5ed, com.ppp.prm.portal.shared.dto.MComments@3de9d6d3, com.ppp.prm.portal.shared.dto.MComments@4316d666, com.ppp.prm.portal.shared.dto.MComments@1055e4f3, com.ppp.prm.portal.shared.dto.MComments@772a15e5, com.ppp.prm.portal.shared.dto.MComments@6c03aa81]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:619)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:539)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:616)

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

RPC 101 - Objects need to implement IsSerializable or Serializable interface. None of the classes ObjectSetFacade  or its super class implement them. Reference more rules - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver

DB4o is non gwt java library. You cannot send com.db4o.internal.query.ObjectSetFacade in any RPC call.

### Solution

1) You should convert from db40 objects to domain objects/pojos compatible with GWT and RPC.

2) Example - we convert Hibernate objects to Domain pojos using Dozer on server. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate

Comment: If your stored objects already can be transfered by GWT. Copy the query result into a GWT compatible type, like a ArrayList.